# Analysis: Proving divergence using partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How do I prove that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ diverges for $s<1$, by estimating its partial sums?

Comment: do you know that the harmonic series is actually diverging? If so, the answer is pretty much straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $s=1$, this series is called the harmonic series, and we can prove directly that it diverges. Note that $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}>\frac{1}{2}$, that $\frac{1}{5}+\space ...\space+\frac{1}{8}>4\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$, and in general that
$$\frac{1}{2^{k-1}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}+2}+\space ...\space+\frac{1}{2^k}\space >2^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence, the $(2^k)^{th}$ partial sum $S_{2^k}$ satisfies $S_{2^k}>1+k\frac{1}{2}$. Since the terms in the harmonic series are all positive, the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing, and by the calculation done the sequence of partial sums is unbounded, and so the sequence of partial sums diverges. Hence, the harmonic series diverges.

Note that for $s<1$, we have that $n^s<n$ (even for $s=0$ or $s$ negative), and hence that $\frac{1}{n^s}>\frac{1}{n}$. Hence, if we let $S_k$ be the $k^{th}$ partial sum of the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, and $T_k$ be the $k^{th}$ partial sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ under consideration, then $T_k>S_k$. Since $\frac{1}{n^s}>0$ for all $n$, we have that $T_k$ is an unbounded monotonically increasing sequence, unbounded since $S_k$ is unbounded by the argument given in the paragraph above, and so $T_k$ diverges. So, by definition, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ diverges.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac1{n^s}=1+\sum_{n=2}^n \frac1{n^s}=1+\int_2^{n+1}\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor^s}dx$$
$$\lfloor x\rfloor<x$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac1{n^s}>1+\int_2^{n+1}\frac1{x^s}dx=1+\frac{1}{1-s}\left[x^{1-s}\right]_2^{n+1}=1+\frac{(n+1)^{1-s}-2^{1-s}}{1-s}$$
Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^s}$ diverges when $s<1$.

---

On the other hand,
$$\lfloor x\rfloor\ge x-1$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac1{n^s}\le1+\int_2^{n+1}\frac1{(x-1)^s}dx=1+\frac{1}{1-s}\left[(x-1)^{1-s}\right]_2^{n+1}=1+\frac{n^{1-s}-1}{1-s}$$
Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^s}$ converges when $s>1$.

Comment: I don't think you have equality between the riemann sum and it's integral, but it is still useful if you can show a property of the function. That the sum is always larger/smalle than the integral of the function would probably suffice.

Comment: There is no equality in the integral and the sum, not in this case.

Comment: you definitely have to change the running variable in your sums, otherwise it's not well defined

Comment: Is it still not same even if I use $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: Yes, it is not the same still @Kay K. You cant equal the sum and the integral because the number of addends is different. And moreover this method isnt the required in the question.

Comment: I think it is same. Otherwise, what's the integral then?

Comment: It is not the same man... A summation have a countable number of addends, a Riemann integral have an uncountable number of addends.

Comment: @Masacroso I appreciate your feedback. I just want to understand why you think it's not same. According to your theory, $1+2=\int_1^3 \lfloor x \rfloor dx$ is also wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see now @Kay K., you are right, your expression is fine. My mistake, thank you very much.

Comment: @Masacroso No problem. Good discussion. I also had a chance to rethink about Riemann integral trying to understand what you said.

Answer (score 1):

It was a long time since I did this, but I think it would work to do a elementwise estimate $$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{n^s}, s \in ]0,1]$$ and using $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
which diverges (it is the famous [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29)).

Answer (score 1):

Write the sum in a fraction and see what happen with the partial sums:

$$\sum_{n=j}^{N}\frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{1}{j^s}+\frac{1}{(j+1)^s}+...+\frac{1}{N^s}=\frac{\sum_{k=j}^{N}\frac{1}{k^s}\left(\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s\right)}{\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s}$$

Now we have that

$$\frac{(N-j+1)\frac{1}{N^s}\left(\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s\right)}{\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s}<\frac{\sum_{k=j}^{N}\frac{1}{k^s}\left(\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s\right)}{\prod_{n=j}^{N} n^s}$$

$$\frac{N-j+1}{N^s}<\sum_{n=j}^{N}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

Then if $\exists N\ \forall j: (j,N\in\Bbb N)\land\left(\frac{N-j+1}{N^s}\ge 1\right)$ then the series is divergent. This is the case for $0<s<1$ because the growth rate of denominator and numerator are different, so you can ever choose some $N$ that make true the above inequality.

Notice that you can prove divergence from this but not convergence i.e. you cant says anything for the cases $s\ge 1$ because the inequality doesnt hold.